# trying to convert a grayscale image to binary, hope anyone can help me

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv

I have a text file from a thermal camera, I read it as an  image with opencv python and it works, then I convert it to gray scale image and it works as well! so I can see the person in the image, the problem is that when I convert it to binary I get a blank black image and I need to draw contours around the person's face. So I wonder what might be the problem.
Hint: The text file is filled with temperature values, when I read it it views the whole person and then I do thresholding to the text file to make the values between 32.0 and 37.0 so that I would show only the face area and it works fine until I try to convert it to binary form.
Thanks in advance.

drive.google.com/file/d/1KgHmPAwcL_uPzVxwkigcQgCsY3jFjx8T/… #link to the file

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

text=np.loadtxt('1_thermal.txt') #the text file of the image
text[text < 32.0]=0 #threshholding to plot and save only the face 
text[text > 37.0]=0
plt.imshow(text,cmap='jet')
plt.savefig('text.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()

person = cv.imread('text.png')
plt.imshow(cv.cvtColor(person, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv.imwrite('person.jpg', person)

# get binary image and apply Gaussian blur
person_gray = cv.cvtColor(person, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
person_preprocessed = cv.GaussianBlur(person_gray, (5, 5), 0)
cv.imwrite('person-Gray.png', person_preprocessed)
plt.imshow(cv.cvtColor(person_preprocessed, cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB))
```

Comment: What method are you using to *"convert to binary form"*? We need more info to help you out. Please update the question with relevant details.

Comment: Since the image is pretty dark, I _guess_ you have to lower the conversion threshold. Hard to tell for sure without seeing your code and having your data.

Comment: Please post your code and your original image, not an image saved from pyplot. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello, I have added the code but I couldn't figure out how to upload the text file!!

Comment: You can always share the text via Dropbox, or Google Drive, or pastebin.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KgHmPAwcL_uPzVxwkigcQgCsY3jFjx8T/view?usp=sharing    #link to the file

Answer (score 1):

You can load the image into a Numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = np.loadtxt('thermal.txt')
```

If we check `im.dtype` and `im.shape`, they are:

```
float64, (288, 382)
```

Now you want a binary image. I presume you mean it will only have values of True/False, so we will need a threshold. As the face is everything above 32, we will use 32 as the threshold:

```
# Threshold - greater than 32 becomes True, all else becomes False
binary = im > 32
```

`binary` will now be True where the face is and False elsewhere, but I guess you want an image that is black (0) where the background is, and white (255) elsewhere. So you want:

```
# Convert from False/True, to 0/255 and save
binary = (binary*255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', binary)
```

That gives:

[image]